# How to correctly call the HeapSummary API in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, heap-memory

I would like to call the `HeapSummary` function from the Win32 API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapsummary

There seems to be missing a list of the possible options for the `dwFlags` parameter. I tried with no flags but `GetLastError()` returns `The parameter is incorrect` error message.

```
    HEAP_SUMMARY heap_summary;
    HeapSummary(GetProcessHeap(), 0, &heap_summary); // Error: The parameter is incorrect
```

Comment: What value did `HeapSummary` return?

Comment: @JonathanPotter It returned false

Comment: Although the Microsoft docs are woefully lacking, I'm guessing the `cb` member needs to be initialised to `sizeof(HEAP_SUMMARY)`.

Comment: Like it says in the documentation for the cb member of HEAP_SUMMARY: "Set this member to sizeof(HEAP_SUMMARY)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jonathan Potter says, We should set the `cb` member to `sizeof(HEAP_SUMMARY)`.

I create a sample to find the reason:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <heapapi.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    HEAP_SUMMARY heap_summary;
    memset(&heap_summary, 0, sizeof(heap_summary));
    HANDLE h = GetProcessHeap();
    HeapSummary(h, 0, &heap_summary); // Error: The parameter is incorrect
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
```

Then step into `HeapSummary` in Disassembly:
[image]

You can see that it compares the passed pointer with `14h (20)`, and push `57h (error 87)` if it is not equal.

So we need to pass in `sizeof(HEAP_SUMMARY)` to the `cb` member of `HEAP_SUMMARY`.

Regarding the problem described in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/ns-heapapi-heap_summary) for `cb`, I will report it to Microsoft for answers.